# Manga about a kid that grew up on a sky island farm and was tasked by a kingdom to rescue the princess

Tags: story-identification, manga

I've forgotten the name of a dark fantasy manga I read.

The story was about a protagonist who is a kid that grew up on a sky island farm and was tasked by a kingdom to rescue the princess. All I remember is that the protagonist used a torch to defeat a demon of some sort.

It's a non-isekai title.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this full colour or mostly black & white?